AOZ1284 SMPS - RC snubber needed?
I'm designing an IoT Edge gateway that I intend to take open source. It's essentially a motherboard with a SMPS and various peripherals (ADCs, digital I/O, RS-485, etc.) and hosting an Orange Pi Zero 3 Linux SBC through the respective headers.
The 5V SMPS is based on an the AOZ1284, for which I reviewed the datasheet and multiple articles. I designed the board to be powered from 12-24VDC, and I paid attention to the layout (to the best of my abilities, that is), but when building the first prototype, and powering it with 12VDC I was surprised that the output voltage was around 1.5V instead of the expected 5V.
As I was measuring the signals with my scope (FNIRSI 1014D), it all started to work just fine, which was a bit of a shocker. Anticipating that there was something lose/cold solder, etc., I reviewed and re-soldered everything just to be sure. Same issue. Whenever I touched the LX pin (FET driver output), the power supply booted just fine.
Just to be sure, I checked many other things, such as the enable pin (voltage perfectly within range), checked component values, etc. Interestingly, once the chip started switching, everything worked very well: very nice regulation, low ripple (around 50mVpp), and more importantly, it reacted very well to input voltage changes, and load changes (which I test by stressing the CPU of the OPI Z3 with the "stress -c 4" Linux command").
During one of my tests, I noticed that lowering the input voltage to 8V allowed the power supply to start just fine. Anything above 10V required the LX pin to be "touched".
While scratching my head, I came across this article which seemed to describe the same, and explained what was going on: by using the scope, the capacitance of the probe acted as a "snubber" and allowed the chip to complete the startup sequence. To confirm this, I added an RC snubber to the board (values chosen by hand to be honest, to c=330pf and r=10ohms), and this solved the problem entirely. From that point, the power supply worked fine regardless of the input power (8 to 30 VDC), and with any load that I could subject it to.
Now here's the issue: there is no mention of an RC snubber in the datasheet. Therefore, I conclude there must be something wrong with my design, and I would like to make it rock-solid, as it would be specially useful for industrial environments.
In addition to all this, I noticed that when powering a light load, specially when VIN=24VDC (i.e. when the switcher is kind of "idle") I can hear a high-pitch noise, as if the switcher actually "stopped" working for short periods of time to prevent the output voltage to go over the required 5V. I've seen this in the past in other switchers mentioned as "discontinuous mode" but I have no idea whether this is supposed to be the case in this chip, and I haven't found any references to anything like that in the spreadsheet.
I'm attaching a few things here for your reference, hoping it helps. These are all WITH  the RC snubber already in place.

Schematic of the power supply

Layout of the power supply section

Voltage at LX pin, light load, VIN=12VDC

Voltage at LX pin, full load, VIN=12VDC

Voltage at LX pin, light load, VIN=24VDC

Voltage at LX pin, full load, VIN=24VDC

"Discontinuous mode" at VIN=24VDC
With all this in mind (thanks for the patience), here are my questions:

Could this be a problem with the layout? For instance, there's a whole GND plane on the bottom layer below the chip and all other components, but it's not connected with any close vias to the top GND plane. I'm no expert, so I would hardly be shocked if this was needed and I overlooked it. Needless to say, I may have committed many other layout crimes. If so, what could I improve?
I feel tempted to leave room in the next prototype iteration for the RC snubber, considering that it seems to have removed the problem altogether. Would this be good, or improving the layout should be enough?
What could I do about the light-load high-pitch sound I hear when the input voltage is high? Should I design the circuit for a lighter load considering it seems a bit over-dimensioned? The board does have a USB port and I would like to leave room for an end-user to plug in something that could draw maybe 500mA, and that's why I like that the current design should allow for up to 5V 4A theoretically, even though the board itself, at full throttle with the CPU at 100% will hardly take more than 600mA (3W).


Could you please add description of what conditions and where the measurement was taken for each of the scope plots?

You have a lot of information here and I apologize for a short followup question. You mentioned that no RC snubber was mentioned in the datasheet. By chance, does the datasheet for that particular product have any errata documentation? If it's a known issue, there's a good chance that the supplier will release errata documents that address common issues. If they do have such documentation, I would have a look at that first and see if they address any design and application changes.

Have you tried reducing C15 to 10 nF or 1nF?

Have you tried connecting Gnd plane to U5-3?  The slow trace shows a lot of instabilities with 50 Hz modulation.

Hi, I added the descriptions of the various captures, thank you BK303 for pointing that out.

Hi Colin, that's a good point. I haven't found any erratas, and there are only a few articles related to this chip out there, so it's hard to know if other people using it needed to resort to this.

Hi D.A.S., that's also what BK303 pointed out. The lack of GND vias (not only at this pin, but in many other places as well) is probably the source of most of this issue.

Certainly adding GND vias to connect the SMT caps on top side to the GND plane (applies to either a bottom or inner GND plane), rather than just using the top-side GND flood will improve this layout. It is common mistake to use top-side broken up fill/flood as substitute for GND plane. The board should be routed as if the top-side fill didn't exist to achieve the full benefit of the GND plane, which means adding lots of additional GND vias. The high current paths of the switcher that should have multiple vias to GND plane include the C7-C10 input caps, D3, and C11-C13 output caps. Plus U5 pin3 should have a ground via for robust connection to C16 and C19 and output caps.
If you have time, before adding vias, I'd modify the placement as shown in this markup in green by rotating two of the 10 µF input caps 180 degrees and move the third closer to output side. Similar I'd rotate and move north the output caps C11, C12, C13 trying to have all the grounds closer together (on north sides). Then after adding GND vias (light blue), add more topside copper to the Vin net as shown with pink markup.

I can't say if those layout changes would fix the issue that required adding LX snubber, but they should make the EMI preformance better.  I'd keep a footprint for the LX snubber in the layout regardless, as can always depopulate those parts.

Thank you for the very thorough explanation. This is my first high-frequency SMS board and I still have a long way to go as far as layouts are concerned. I will follow all your recommendations in the next prototype run next week. Do you have any comments in relation to the high-pitch sound when the power supply is "idle"? This corresponds to the last capture in my post, in which it can be seen that the chip is turning the switcher on an off at intervals. Maybe I should start a separate thread about that.

I agree with you that the controller seems to enter some discontinuous (or PWM) mode, and that may have slower frequency pattern that results in some audible switching.  Certainly I've seen/heard plenty of switched mode power supplies in full production products that exhibit some audible squeaking or squealing or buzzing under some load conditions, so despite it being annoying, it may be harmless.  Not sure what else to recommend there, could maybe try adding a bright blue LED to draw some minimum power and see if that changes anything (other than keeping the room lit at night).
